# Emacs org-agenda-list destroy my windows splits

Tags: emacs

I found answer thanks to #org-mode group on freenode

---

I have problem with `org-agenda-list` and `org-todo-list` functions, they break my windows splits and split emacs to 2 equal windows, is there any way to fix it? Or any other function for load todo/agenda in current active window? I have workaround with winner-undo (but it pissing me off).

Emacs window layout before function calls
[image: Before function call]

Emacs after functions call
[image]

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Set org-agenda-window-setup in your init.el

```
(setq org-agenda-window-setup 'current-window)
```

Thanks to quicksilver from #org-mode on freenode

Type `C-h v org-agenda-window-setup` for other options.

Comment: You, sir, deserve a cookie! Thank you!

Comment: `M-x customize-group org-agenda-windows` works with the default customization framework.

Comment: (setq org-agenda-restore-windows-after-quit t)
To not have to use the current window and restore what you had after pressing q to quit.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way is to use default Emacs customization:

```
M-x customize-group org-agenda-windows
```

There are several options, including current window. Try them out, I think one of them will do what you need.